# Is my negation statement about finite groups correct ($a^n = e$ for some $n$)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

This problem appears as an exercise labeled middle-Level problem in the book of Abstract Algebra by I. N. Herstein (Third edition) section 2.1 Definitions and Examples of Groups, it says:

> If $G$ is a finite group, prove that, given $a\in G$, there is a positive integer $n$, depending on $a$, such that $a^n = e$

I state the negation as:

If $G$ is a finite group, then there exists $a \in G$ which for all integer $n$, depending on $a$, such that $a^n \neq e$.

Am I correct at this point? Is this the right way to negate the statement? If so the proof is very easy now, but if is not, which is the correct way? Is the same as contrapositive?

### Edit

Now thanks to your replies I think I spot some errors at my orginal negation, now I will write something like:

If $G$ is a finite group, then there exists $a \in G$ which, for all positive integer $n$, $a^n≠e$. Is this now correct?

Comment: No. You have to remove "depending on $a$", otherwise it doesn't really make sense.

Comment: I was thinking so, but I was a little confused. Thanks.

Comment: But I would say that proof by contradiction is not the way to go here.

Comment: Yes, that's right, there is no need of contradiction, instead there is a neat direct proof, but ironically I reach that solution exploring the contradiction.

Comment: "There exists $a\in G$ which for all $n$, depending on $a$, such that $a^n=e$." Not only is it not true that $n$ should "depend" on $a$, but to a native English speaker it should be clear this sentence is gibberish because it doesn't actually *say* anything at all. Imagine if you structured a nonmathematical sentence like this: "there's a person which for all times, depending on the person, such that the person knows what time it is" is the *beginning* of a sentence which is missing an end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above answer is a satisfactory one and has got the essence of what I am compelled to write below. I am just interested in seeing how the rules of logic may be at our help.

Your statement is of the form $(\forall x) P(x) $,  where $P(x) $ is a predicate on the domain $G$. Now, the negation of such a statement is $(\exists x) \sim P(x) $, where $\sim$ is the negation symbol. Hence we just need to check what will be $(\exists x) \sim P(x) $.

In your case,

> $P(x) :$ $\textit{$\exists$ $n$ such that $x^n =e$}$

Now, negation of the statement of the form $(\exists y) Q(y) $ is $(\forall y) \sim Q(y) $.

Hence for your case

> $\sim P(x) : (\forall n) \, \, x^n \neq e$.

Now, finally, $(\exists x) \sim P(x)$ takes the form

> There exists $x$ such that for all $n$ we have $x^n \neq e$.

I must ask apology for mixing up the symbolic and verbal forms. But the essence that I wanted to convey is the above one.

Comment: I think this is the most clear way to show how the negation is formed. Thank you so much, I really appreciate!

Comment: Glad that it helped.

Answer (score 2):

So the statement says that if $G$ is a finite group, for each $g\in G$ you pick, you can find $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $a^n=e$. To negate such statements, we must ask: how this can never be true? That is, what is the complete opposite of the statement?

If for every element $s$ of a set $S$ we have a property $p(s)$, to negate (to find the opposite) is to state that there exists an element of the set $S$ such that the property that doesn't hold (because how can every element has such property and, at the same time, we can find an element that does not have such property?).

Can you see how we can use the same rationale to negate your statement?

Also, for his exercise I would advise use the fact that if $G$ is finite, then we can write $\{e,a_1,...,a_m\}$ for some $m\in\mathbb{N}$. Now start to take the powers $a,a^2,a^3,...,a^m,a^{m+1},...$ that are all in $G$. Because there are much more elements in the list $a,a^2,a^3,...,a^m,a^{m+1},...$ that in $G$ but they are all in $G$, there must be repeated elements, right?

Comment: First, thanks for your advice in solving this exercise, I understand the idea of the solution.  And indeed I think I solved that way, at the end I have something like: $ a^l = a^j $ for some $ l \neq j $ positive integers, and assuming that $l>j$ then $l-j = r \in \mathbb{Z}^+$  and $a^l = a^j$ becomes $a^{l-j} = e$ that is $a^r = e$ for some positive integer $r$. I reach to this exploring the negation.

Comment: Second, now my main concern is about the negation statement, I already catch some mistakes, so now I will write something like this: If G is a finite group, then there exists $a \in G$ which for all positive integer n,  $a^n \neq e$. Is this now correct?

Comment: @JoséMarín about the first comment: yes! that's exactly the point. About the second comment, not quite, because first, if you negate that $G$ is a finite group, then what you have is an infinite group

Comment: @JoséMarín also, the negation of the statement is not quite right as well. If we want to negate a "for all x we have property p" we must find a $x_0$ that does not obey the property, in this case the negation of the statement is that there exists an element $a$ such that for every $n$ in $\mathbb{N}$ we get $a^n\neq e$, can you see why?

Comment: I see, but as far as I can remember, in order to use contradiction it is necessary to hold the hypothesis (for example in this case G is finite) and negate the thesis.

Comment: yeah, I write that way of negation at the question Edit. If that's correct, I think I can close the question now.

Comment: @JoséMarín yes, to use proof by contradiction you negate the statement and find something wrong. So, in this case, we are assuming that $G$ is finite, and we suppose, to get the contradiction, that your statement does not hold, so in this case that there is an element such that $a^n\neq e$ for all $n$. In this case the goal is to find something incompatible between our hypothesis that $G$ is finite and our assumption that we can find such element

Answer (score 2):

To understand that your "depending on $a$" is spurious, perhaps formalizing a bit may help: $\neg(\forall a\in G, \exists n\in\Bbb N\mid a^n=e) \iff$ $\exists a\in G\mid \forall n\in\Bbb N, a^n\ne e$.